# 'cannot import name 'binom_test' from 'scipy.stats'' error when using borutashap

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use borutashap for feature selection of a machine learning project.
I can't run:

```
from BorutaShap import BorutaShap
```

always came across this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'binom_test' from 'scipy.stats'
```

I upgraded both borutashap and scipy to make sure they are the latest version.
I am using a conda env, and I removed the whole env and recreated a new env and reinstalled all libraries, but still the same mistake.
Could anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `scipy.stats.binom_test()` was removed from SciPy 1.12.0. [Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release/1.12.0-notes.html#expired-deprecations).

There is an alternative, `scipy.stats.binomtest()`, which is called slightly differently. Here are the docs for [old](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.11.4/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) and [new](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binomtest.html).

I believe you could fix this either by downgrading SciPy to 1.11.0 or by applying a fix to BorutaShap to call the new binomial test function.

I believe you'd need to install the package in editable form, then edit `Boruta-Shap/src/BorutaShap.py` to do this, on two lines:

Line 9:

Change

```
from scipy.stats import binom_test, ks_2samp
```

to

```
from scipy.stats import binomtest, ks_2samp
```

Line 885:

Change

```
        return [binom_test(x, n=n, p=p, alternative=alternative) for x in array]
```

to

```
        return [binomtest(x, n=n, p=p, alternative=alternative).pvalue for x in array]
```

I'd suggest filing an issue on GitHub about this - the author is probably more likely to see it and fix it.

Comment: Thank you Nick.
Your suggestion makes much sense.
TBH, I got the issue resolved before seeing your answer, by creating a new environment, installing all the packages, and intalling BorutaShap without intalling shap.
Now the scipy version is 1.11.4, and borutashap is 1.0.17, and everything is working fine.
I have also raised an issue on GitHub.
Thank you again for your help!